# Vue.js Json data in other components looks like array of [object Object]

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, promise, vuex

I have this code in my HomePage component

```
data() {
  return {
    prodlist: []
  }
},
created(){
const vm = this
vm.axios.get(myUrl, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: vm.$store.getters.myBearer
  }
})
.then(response => {
    vm.prodlist = response.data
    return resp
  })
.then(response => {
    this.$store.dispatch('GET_ALL_DATA', response)
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data)
    console.log(error.response.status)
    console.log(error.response.headers)
  })
```

when i use my prodlist array in current component - it's ok, but when I'm trying to use vuex getter in other component, like ProductList for example (or in header for searching) - in any other
I'm gettin [object Object],[object Object] ....
as I undestood during reading tens of questions and articles, this is because my promise still processing,

But I still can't adjust them to my code. This is not about stupidity, I'm starting to learn JS only 3 month ago. Can somebody help me with my own situatuion?

So question is - how to use my data correctly - wait for processing(how then to do it), or maybe make a request in main component, or in header (because they are loading first) i need access to this data in header for searching, and in other components as a list of all products, list of best prods an so on
It's not a real project I just train my skills on real-like situation
I will be glad to any advice.  Thank you.

here is the store.js

```
state: {
  allDataObj: {
    gettingJsongObj: {}
  },
},
mutations: {
  PAGE_DATA_RECIEVED (state, payload) {
    state.allDataObj.gettingJsongObj = payload
  }
},
actions: {
  GET_ALL_DATA: ({commit}, payload) => {
    commit('PAGE_DATA_RECIEVED', payload)
  }
},
getters: {
  bigObjectGetter: state => {
    return state.allDataObj.gettingJsongObj
  }
}
```

Comment: don't know how you expect us to help you without sharing what `'GET_ALL_DATA` does or what the vuex getter looks like that you are using in that other component ...

Comment: You could create a small example on a jsfiddle or plunker making use of a public API (github has public API)

Comment: i got info from api and it works in curernt component , i need just wait for a promise completes his process, so question was about this